# Return the number of unique number values in the array "arr"

Tags: java, arrays, loops, return, unique

I am looking for a way to find the number of unique number values in an array.

I can't use imports for this project but I can use loops and conditional statements.

For instance the array

```java
int[] arr1 = {3, -3, -1,  0, -1,  4,  0,  3,  4,  0};
```

should return 5

Here's what I came up with so far:

```java
public static int countUniqueIntegers(int[] arr){
    
    // Initialize int "counter" with value 0
    int num_unique = 0;
    
    // TO DO: Add logic to count unique values
    if(arr.length == 0) return 0;
    if(arr.length == 1) return 1;
    double currentNumber = arr[0];
    int currentCount =1;
    for(int i =1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      if(arr[i] != currentNumber)
      {
        currentCount++;
        currentNumber = arr[i];
      }
    }
    // Return number of unique values
    return num_unique;
  }
```

Comment: And what is your question? Have a look at [ask] on how to ask a good question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822 on how to ask a question about homework

Comment: I need help with getting the output its not working with the code I have created. Is there something I am doing wrong or a better method to what I am looking for? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using sets?  You only need a single loop to do this.

Comment: @WJS That would count as an `import` I would assume.

Comment: @TimHunter ah!  Missed that one.

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr1).distinct().count());` prints 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start with an assumption that every value in array is unique. So number of unique values at the start is the same as array length.
After this, we have to compare every value in the array with every other value in the same array. For this you need another "for" loop inside your "for" loop. If current item from outside (first) loop equals some item from inside loop, you just subtract 1 from your variable with unique numbers count (i.e. array length at the start).
All you have to do now - programm it :)